# Updating fragment 1 UI from fragment 2

Tags: android, android-fragments

frag1 calls frag 2 and frag 2 calls a method in frag1 that updates a textview. The code works (doesn't crash) but the frag1 UI (when I return from frag2) is not updated/

Is it a valid approach? Is there a way to update the UI?

here is the frag1 and frag2 code:

```
public class Frag1 extends android.app.Fragment {
    private static TextView txt;
    public Frag1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = null;
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag1, container, false);
        return rootview;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        txt = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txt);
        Button btn = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Frag2 f2 = new Frag2();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, f2);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });

    }

    void setTxt(String s){
        txt.setText(s);
    }

}
```

and frag2 - the setTxt() method updates the textview in frag1:

```
public class Frag2 extends Fragment {
    private Button btn2;

    public Frag2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview;
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag2, container, false);
        Log.i("frag2","createdview");
        return rootview;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Frag1 f1 = new Frag1();
        f1.setTxt("msg from frag2");

        btn2 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Frag3 f3 = new Frag3();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, f3);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Broadcast Intent from the  frag2

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("key_to_identify_the_broadcast");
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("edttext", json.toString());
    intent.putExtra("bundle_key_for_intent", bundle);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and then you can receive the bundle in your frag 1 by using the BroadcastReceiver class

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new 
BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = 
            intent.getExtras().getBundle("bundle_key_for_intent");
            if(bundle!=null){
                String edttext = bundle.getString("edttext");
            }
            //you can call any of your methods for using this bundle for your use case
    }
};
```

in onCreateView() of your fragment you need to register the broadcast receiver first otherwise this broadcast receiver will not be triggered

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("key_to_identify_the_broadcast");
getActivity().getApplicationContext().
               registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, filter);
```

Finally you can unregister the receiver to avoid any exceptions

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    try {

         getActivity().getApplicationContext().
             unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("UnRegister Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

You can create separate broadcast receivers in all of your fragments and use the same broadcast to broadcast the data to all of your fragments. You can also use different keys for different fragments and then broadcast using particular key for particular fragment.

Comment: I'm not clear. What provides me the broadcast mechanism. The communication of the data between fragments? at the end I want to update a textview. I am still in frag2: I broadcast the data to frag1 and then what happens? It seems to me that the problem is more an update of the UI rather that data exchange between fragments? Thanks.

Comment: Through broadcast you will know when you have to set UI or view!